# Move OS X Dock to other monitor programmatically

Tags: macos, shell, applescript

I'm using 2 external monitors with my rMBP (one via thunderbolt/DVI and one via HDMI). The lid of the laptop is closed. Is it possible to move the Dock and the Menu Bar from one display to the other (ie. make it the main display) **programmatically**?

I use [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/) to detect certain situations and I'd like to swap the main monitor if a situation occurs with a script (like bash or AppleScript).

I looked in the `com.apple.dock.plist` but didn't find any key that I could use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with a command line tool I wrote [here](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/hmscreens/hmscreens.html). There's an example applescript to show you how it might be used.

Comment: Just what I was looking for.  Thanks for the software regulus663!

Comment: Since that link is broken, I found this fork: https://github.com/mikeakers/hmscreens

Note: I haven't tested it, for most stuff like this I have used [displayplacer](https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer)